# Querying DynamoDB with partition key and secondary index in Javascript

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk-js, aws-sdk-nodejs

Having the following table definition in DynamoDB

```
pk: userId (string)
sk: carId (string)
index: carModelIndex (string)
```

If I would like to query all the cars rented by a given user for a given model. How I would go about that?.

Please note I am using the javascript sdk for dynamodb.

Comment: What's the primary key in your index ?

Comment: The primary key in my index is carModelIndex. Thanks